# Is there any toolbox for Markov Random Field Structure Learning?

Tags: markov-chains, hidden-markov-models, graphical-models

I need a toolbox or software that takes a dataset as input, detect independencies among its random variables and produces the relative Markov Random Field graphical structure from that. Can anyone suggest a proper toolbox for doing this task automatically?

Comment: Try looking into Graphical LASSO, maybe it'll fit what you're trying to do (if you're working with Gaussians)

Comment: I think that requests for software recommendations are off-topic here.  Any community votes?